# Are there any studies on the effectiveness of school trips abroad on language learning?

Tags: reference-request

In the UK, stricter [health and safety regulations have made school trips abroad harder to organize](https://www.britishcouncil.org/voices-magazine/whats-happening-language-learning-english-schools) and this has reduced the number of opportunities for British children to experience a foreign language first hand. Some teachers resort to social media as an alternative for trips abroad and language exchanges, even though many think they are no substitute for real-life communication with native speakers.

How big is the impact of this loss of opportunities? More specifically, what is the effect of such school trips on language learning? Have their been any studies on this topic?

Comment: Are you asking about trips that last for a few days/a week or rather exchange programmes with some month duration?

Comment: @Marzipanherz School trips of any duration. They need to be organised by the school and involve all pupils in a class, so exchange programmes for individual pupils are outside the scope of this question.